# Simplify the codes for some repeated actions by creating loops

Tags: c++

Here below are my codes performing data resetting for a series of ports of integer type.

```
   //note function: void resetData(int pin);
   resetData(p00);
   resetData(p01);
   resetData(p02);
   resetData(p03);
   resetData(p04);
   resetData(p05);
   resetData(p06);
   resetData(p07);

   resetData(p10);
   resetData(p11);
   resetData(p12);
   resetData(p13);
   resetData(p14);
   resetData(p15);
   resetData(p16);
   resetData(p17);

   resetData(p50);
   resetData(p51);

resetData(p80);
resetData(p81);
resetData(p82);
resetData(p83);
resetData(p84);
resetData(p85);
resetData(p86);
resetData(p87);

resetData(p110);
resetData(p111);
resetData(p112);
resetData(p113);
resetData(p114);
resetData(p115);
resetData(p116);
resetData(p117);
```

In the above codes, there are different types of ports (as grouped together), and they are processed by `resetData`. Is there way to simplify these long list of code by creating some loops, without changing the definition of `resetData`? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just put all the pins you want to reset into an `std::vector<int>` and loop over that?

Comment: There absolutely is a way to simplify it using loops: why don't you show us what you've tried, and we'll help with any issues you ran into from there?

Comment: @UnholySheep: there is one way I am trying. It still needs to create a vector by putting these ports individually. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function that works on groups of pins:

```
void myResetData(const std::vector<int> &pins)
{
    for (auto pin : pins)
    {
        resetData(pin);
    }
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
void f()
{
    std::vector<int> group1{ p00, p01, p02, p03, p04, p05, p06, p07 },
                     group2{ p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17 };
    myResetData(group1);
    myResetData(group2);
}
```

or just:

```
void f()
{
    myResetData(std::vector<int>{ p00, p01, p02, p03, p04, p05, p06, p07 });
    myResetData(std::vector<int>{ p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17 });
}
```

You may even get away with:

```
void f()
{
    myResetData({ p00, p01, p02, p03, p04, p05, p06, p07 });
    myResetData({ p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int ports[] = {p00,p01,p02,p03,p04,p05,p06,p07,
               p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,
               p50,p51,
               p80,p81,p82,p83,p84,p85,p86,p87,
               p110,p111,p112,p113,p114,p115,p116,p117};
int portsNum = sizeof(ports)/sizeof(*ports);
for(int i=0;i<portsNum;i++)
{
    resetData(ports[i]);
}
```